# Format date in Angular based on Timezone

Tags: angular, angular-date-format

I'm receiving dates from my API that are in UTC format.  I need to output the dates using the user's local timezone.  Each user is assigned a timezone that I pull from a different API.

Using the following documentation I was able to make things work for all time zones with a + (i.e. +100, +200, etc.).  However when I have a timezone with a - (i.e. -800).  This does not work.

**Works:**

```
{{element.myDate | date:'d-MMM-yyyy HH:mm' : '+800' }}
```

Orginal Value: 7-Jan-2019 00:46

New Value: 7-Jan-2019 16:46

**Does NOT Work (timezone is ignored):**

```
{{element.myDate | date:'d-MMM-yyyy HH:mm' : '-800' }}
```

Orginal Value: 7-Jan-2019 00:46

New Value: 7-Jan-2019 00:46

**Angular Class used after calling API**

```
export class MyClass {
  constructor(
    public myDate: Date,
    public otherData: string
  ) {}
}
```

Comment: It works. The default timezone of `DatePipe` is your local timezone, which is `GMT-8` or `-800` in Seattle.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Thanks for the feedback, but I've tried this and no change occurs as I've mentioned above.

Comment: My point is that both of your examples work. The timezone `-800` is not ignored. In your first example, you can see that `+800` adds 16 hours to the "original value". Therefore, that original value is for the timezone `-800`. That is why the value does not change when you specify `-800`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I get it now.  When the date is loaded on the browser it assumes that it is my local timezone even though I stored it as UTC on the server.  As you and I are both in Pacific time there is no change when we use -800.  However, when I use -1600 I get the result I was looking for.  In the short term this will work for me, but is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: How do you create `myDate`? By the way, I am in Quebec. :-)

Comment: From my service in Angular, I'm pulling myDate from an API (.NET Core FYI), and then filling a model on the angular side.  I also added this class as part of the original question.  I'm in California, thanks for the help!

Comment: You can convert the date to UTC before showing the result in the view, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9dzbst?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). I will post an answer if this is what you want.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Post your stackblitz and I'll mark it as the solution.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I suggest to use date getTimezoneOffset() to get timezone offset instead of hard coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the date is considered as "local" in Angular, you can first convert it to UTC, and show the result in the view. The conversion method below assumes that a `myUtcDate` property is present in the element class:

```
this.myUtcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(
  this.myDate.getFullYear(),
  this.myDate.getMonth(),
  this.myDate.getDate(),
  this.myDate.getHours(),
  this.myDate.getMinutes(),
  this.myDate.getSeconds()
));
```

```
{{ element.myUtcDate | date:'d-MMM-yyyy HH:mm' : '-800' }}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9dzbst?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.